# How to Redesigning a method in order for it to work

Tags: java, list, for-loop, hashmap, set

My code results in an java.util.ConcurrentModificationException error. Here is the following code.

Here is the exact error:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:894)
        at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:928)
        at ca.on.oicr.pinery.lims.gsle.GsleClient.getOrders(GsleClient.java:720)
```

Line 720 is the second for loop

I posted this question before and was told that "You're adding to orders inside a loop that's looping over the elements of orders, that's what causes the exception. Don't modify a collection you're looping over inside the loop. Likewise with samples". I understand that I to re construct this method and received the following suggestions.

```
ListIterator<Order> it = orders.listIterator();

while ( it.hasNext() ) {
      Order ord = it.next();

      if ( ) // some condition
        it.remove(); // This wil remove the element that we just got using the next() method
      if ( ) // some other condition
        it.add(new Order()); // THis inserts the element immediately before the next call to next()
}
```

Now I am stuck at how to do the adding of the samples and the order when using the iteration method since you would iterate differently though a set, I assume I would use a for loop.

This is the part I am getting confused on how to change in order to not get the java.util.ConcurrentModificationException.

```
f
```

So far I have gotten up to here.

```
  java.util.ListIterator<Order> it = orders.listIterator();
  while (it.hasNext()) {
     it.next().getId();
     if (sampleOrderMap.containsKey((it.next().getId())))
     {
        Set<OrderSample> samples = sampleOrderMap.get(it.next().getId());

     }

  }`
```

I just do not know how to put in the rest in a way that I would not get the ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: You can have some temporary collection to add to other than the one you are iteration through.

Then, after you finish iterating, you add the new temp collection to the original.

Comment: This question needs a title change. Not exactly sure what to make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Java Docs:

ConcurrentModificationException may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent modification of an object when such modification is not permissible.
For example, it is not generally permissible for one thread to modify a Collection while another thread is iterating over it. In general, the results of the iteration are undefined under these circumstances. Some Iterator implementations (including those of all the general purpose collection implementations provided by the JRE) may choose to throw this exception if this behavior is detected. Iterators that do this are known as fail-fast iterators, as they fail quickly and cleanly, rather that risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has been concurrently modified by a different thread. If a single thread issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of an object, the object may throw this exception. For example, if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception.

Note that fail-fast behavior cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast operations throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: ConcurrentModificationException should be used only to detect bugs.

To go around this, you can create a temporary collection to add to other than the one you are iterating through.

Then, after you finish iterating, you can use orders.AddAll(tempCollection) to add the new items.

Comment: your answer is same as your comment

Comment: @SSP Which is perfectly okay if the comment is worthy of being an answer. That being said, a little bit of elaboration in this case might be good for the answer.

Comment: when i "add the new temp collection to the original" would I have to iterate through the orders to get it into each order?

Comment: @user2811419 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)

Comment: @SSP, Cruncher, good points, I should elaborate some more. Moved it to an answer as I thought that it is an answer to the question, and since it was not answered yet.